# how to display post in jquery slider and carousel

Tags: jquery

ok I'm pretty new to wordpress and the codex seems too complicated for a newbie like me. My homepage has both a  [slider](http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/)(which I want it to display `5` latest post) and a [carousel](http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/)(which should display `4` older post)

I know wordpress uses the query_post() function to display the posts but my problem is how to employ this function in both the carousel and the slider (which are both on the homepage). :(

Answer (score 0):

You want [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) not `query_posts`. Only use the latter if you need to modify the main query.

Something like this (in whatever template file you want):

```
<ul class="slider">
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
    setup_postdata($post); 
?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Rinse, lather, repeat with necessary parameters for carousel.